# PHP foreach loops and data retrieval

Tags: php, arrays, loops, oop, foreach

Using PHP and MySQL I have generated two arrays. I would like to loop through these arrays, retrieve data from both and display together in one sentence.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if(isset($item->item_title)) {
        $itemTitle = $item->item_title;
    }
    // var_dump($itemTitle);
    // string(7) "Halfway" string(5) "Story" string(6) "Listen" 
}

foreach ($aData["Items"]["Item"] as $a) {
    if (isset($a['description'])) {
        $aDescription   = $a['description'];
    }
    // var_dump($aDescription   );
    // string(4) "Good" string(6) "Strong" string(2) "OK" 
}

?>
```

Desired result;

```
The title is Halfway and the description is Good.
The title is Story and the description is Strong.
The title is Listen and the description is OK.
// etc
// etc
```

Is it possible to nest the `foreach` loops, or is there a better more efficient way?

Comment: Please share your input array.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that data. If there are certain methods or functions you can recommend i'm willing to have a look at them myself. I just need a nudge in the right direction! The logic is throwing me off :/

Comment: I hope my post will help you with the same as you are expecting.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question with any level of certainty when they don't know what your arrays look like.  Any/all of the answers make the same basic assumptions and illustrate similar concepts of multi-dimensional array referencing. Read the array section of the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way. Hope this help!!

```
foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    if(isset($item->item_title)) {
        $itemTitle = $item->item_title;
        echo 'The title is '.$itemTitle;
    }
    if(isset($aData["Items"]["Item"][$index]['description']) {
        $itemDescription = $aData["Items"]["Item"][$index]['description'];
        echo ' and the description is '.$itemDescription;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    // The title is Halfway and the description is Good. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help you out.

> **Note:** Here i am assuming both array's have same indexes.

`$items` 
`$aData["Items"]["Item"]`.

> If not you can do `array_values($items)` and `array_values($aData["Items"]["Item"])`

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item)
{
    if (isset($item->item_title) && isset($aData["Items"]["Item"][$key]['description']))
    {
        $itemTitle = $item->item_title;
        echo sprinf("The title is %s and the description is %s",$itemTitle,$aData["Items"]["Item"][$key]['description']);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge those two `foreach` loops using a simple `for` loop, like this:

```
$count = count($items) >= count($aData["Items"]["Item"]) ? count($aData["Items"]["Item"]) : count($items);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
    if(isset($item[$i]->item_title)) {
        $itemTitle = $item[$i]->item_title;
    }
    if (isset($aData["Items"]["Item"][$i]['description'])) {
        $aDescription   = $aData["Items"]["Item"][$i]['description'];
    }
    // your code
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** The above code assumes that two arrays `$items` and `$aData["Items"]["Item"]` have unequal number of elements, though this will work for equal number of elements as well. If you're sure that these two arrays will always have equal number of elements, then refactor the `$count = ... ;` statement in the following way,

```
$count = count($items);
```

or

```
$count = count($aData["Items"]["Item"]);
```

and use this `$count` variable in `for` loop.